# My kids won't "go to bed when it's time"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

My children in Skyrim sometimes do not follow their commands. I told both of them (Lucia and Blaise) to go to bed and they said "Yes, ma" and just stood there.

My home is in Whiterun, with the name Breezehome. It gets quite annoying, especially when they block the entrance of their room and I can't get in to check their chests. If there is any way to stop it or fix it, I need to know. Or just a way to avoid it or how to ignore it would be useful, too. I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: I find flogging helps discipline them most of the time.

Comment: Ignoring it is one way to ignore it.

Comment: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/? Oh wait, maybe not.

Comment: Concerning the blocked entrance, sprinting "through" them will cause them to step aside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the [Skyrim Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Child):

> After telling adopted children to go to bed, they will instead appear to sit on thin air or refuse to perform any other animations.
>
> Can be fixed by simply saving and reloading.

I presume it's one of those bugs that have yet to be fixed, and unfortunately until then I don't think there's much more of a solution.

Save -> Reload -> They should be asleep upon re-load.

Comment: Helpful answer, but it'd also be good to link to your source

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I'll be sure to do so in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Download the **Unofficial Hearthfire Patch** to fix it. This is a bug some people encountered. if that doesn't work, reload any saves or save and reload yourself. Or try to wait a few days and when it's night tell them to go to bed and they should do it. If that doesn't work, then I don't know what else to do then.